Partial errors computing affine transform with OpenCV
I've been working a lot with OpenPnP recently (which is great!), and have had my interest peaked enough to try and really understand it's workings.
I am trying to produce a basic transformation of a PCB with 3 fiducials, and 3 features, in C# with OpenCVSharp.
I've modelled the geometry in some CAD software to sanity check again, here is my 'PCB'.
F1-3 are the 3 fiducials, with F1 being 0,0 of the PCB coordinate system. P1-3 are the 3 'features' on the PCB that I'm interested in.

Here is that 'PCB' superimposed on a 'machine', where the green dot is the machine's 0,0. So from this I've essentially got already what the 3 features locations would be, relative to the machine 0,0.

I think I need to do an 'affine transform', and over a few hours have pulled this together.
using OpenCvSharp;

namespace affinetransform
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Define fiducials in PCB coordinates
            Point2f[] pcbFiducials = new Point2f[]
            {
                new Point2f(0, 0),
                new Point2f(100, 0),
                new Point2f(100, -80)
            };

            // Corresponding fiducial points as measured in machine coordinates
            Point2f[] cameraFiducials = new Point2f[]
            {
                new Point2f(190.62f, -83.7f),
                new Point2f(290.24f, -74.99f),
                new Point2f(297.21f, -154.68f)
            };

            // Compute the affine transformation matrix
            Mat affineTransform = Cv2.GetAffineTransform(InputArray.Create(pcbFiducials), InputArray.Create(cameraFiducials));

            // Define the 3 'features' on the PCB we're interested in, in PCB coordinates
            Point2f[] pcbFeatures = new Point2f[]
            {
                new Point2f(24, -18),
                new Point2f(35, -62),
                new Point2f(74, -28)
            };

            // Convert feature points to a Mat object, because we need to pass Mat type to the Transform method
            Mat pcbFeaturesMat = new Mat(pcbFeatures.Length, // Rows
                                            1,                  // Columns
                                            MatType.CV_32FC2,
                                            pcbFeatures);       // The features on the PCB we want to transform
            for (int i = 0; i < pcbFeaturesMat.Rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < pcbFeaturesMat.Cols; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{pcbFeaturesMat.At<float>(i, j)}\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }


            // Transform feature points to machine/camera coordinates
            Mat cameraFeaturesMat = new Mat();
            Cv2.Transform(pcbFeaturesMat, cameraFeaturesMat, affineTransform);

            // Save the transformed points to a CSV file
            SavePointsToCsv(cameraFeaturesMat, @"C:\users\user\desktop\cameraFeatures.csv");
        }

        static void SavePointsToCsv(Mat points, string filename)
        {
            using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("X,Y");
                for (int i = 0; i < points.Rows; i++)
                {
                    float x = points.At<float>(i, 0);
                    float y = points.At<float>(i, 1);
                    writer.WriteLine($"{x},{y}");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Saved transformed points to {filename}");
        }
    }
}

And this is the transformed data it outputs, which is not completely wrong. As you can see from my images, 216.09, 230.89 and 266.78 are the 3 correct transformed values of X in that table, but in the wrong positions - with the remaining 3 data points just being the machine X position of F1, repeated twice, and a huge number.
X,Y
216.09705,230.88875
230.88875,266.7783
266.7783,1.11E-43

The affine transform matrix itself computed by this code is:
Transformation Matrix:
0.99619995117187, -0.08712501525878906, 190.6199951171875
0.08709999084472657, 0.9961249351501464, -83.69999694824219

Completely stumped, and hoping some smart OpenCV folk can point me in the right direction!

mats have rows, columns, and depth/channels. you want a "single column" matrix with 32FC2 (2-channel) data. give it a try. your transform matrix is probably okay but pcbFeaturesMat probably not. I'm surprised whatever wrapper you use didn't complain about the mismatch between the given Point2f[] and the constructor arguments -- I couldn't actually test your code. I'm not set up for C#. let me know if that's the issue. then I'll make an answer out of it.

does the matrix look something like this? [[0.9962, -0.08713, 190.62], [0.0871, 0.99612, -83.7]] I'm getting this for the transform(): [[ 216.09705,  -99.53985], [ 230.88875, -142.41124], [ 266.7783 , -105.1461 ]] (tested with Python and no issues with the data conversion because that doesn't happen with Python/numpy/OpenCV)

I'd recommend taking the PNP system as the world frame, then locate the fiducials on the pcb, and calculate a transform between the PNP frame and the the PCB frame.

Thanks for your comments @ChristophRackwitz. pcbFeaturesMat is already of type 32FC2 in my example code, unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Will grab matrix values shortly, AFK right now, but your calculated trasformed values arenindeed correct in both X and Y! Ref your world frame recommendation, I think maybe I don't understand the terminology - isn't that what I have done? My green point represents 0,0 of the machine, and I've 'captured' the fiducial values relative to that point.

I've added the matrix values to my question, which are the same as yours (just to more decimal places). So that's something!

I've also realised by transformed XY data I somehow must have copied wrong, and one of the values is not what this code generates, so I've fixed that.

did you understand my point about single-column?

No, I don't think so. In the constructor for the pcbFeaturesMat, if I change 2 to a 1, the resulting transformation is still incorrect, so I guess that tells me I'm still stumped! Really appreciate any steer you can provide here.

That makes sense, because that value keeps changing each time I run the program, so I agree - definitely uninitialized. Ref your "single-column" comment, does this mean  Mat pcbFeaturesMat = new Mat() should be passed 1, instead of 2, for the columns argument?

it might still be incorrect but it's less wrong. that one E+21 number is uninitialized memory. I'm familiar with OpenCV's C++ and Python APIs but not this third party C# wrapper. perhaps check pcbFeaturesMat in isolation. I find that the most likely candidate for an issue. check its resulting shape, channel count, element type, and its values. if the values don't match what you passed to the constructor... -- I can't predict what the Mat constructor does with an array of Point2f. might be references, might be six contiguous floats packed in memory.

pcbFeaturesMat is of type 3x2xCV_32FC2, and it's data is as below, which doesn't feel right. 24, 35 and 74 should all be in the X column. [24, 35, ][74, 0][3.5096498E-20, 0]

yes, and I said that's wrong. it must be single column.

So, I've updated the question with the change the constructor for a single column wide, still using CV_32FC2 data types, and the output from the transform. The affine matrix remains unchanged, but the transform is still wrong (still contains 3 correct values however). So, I'm still at a loss as to what is off here, has to be something to do with datatypes expected by the wrapper.

You mentioned you'd set this up in Python, I've got a Python 3 environment setup here too, any chance you could share your code and I can work through that to see if there are any differences?

on the python side, it's just a couple of np.float32([ [a,b], [c,d], [e,f] ]).reshape((3, 1, 2)). you might need to wait for someone who knows the C# wrapper's peculiarities, and C#'s peculiarities

I've just noticed, whilst the affineTransform matrix is correct, it's type is 23CV_64FC1, which doe not match the CV_32FC2 types for the fiducials and points, is that an issue?

not an issue as such, unless C#/wrapper-level type conversions are involved that seem prone to failing, if the user isn't exact about it. the C++ API itself, specifically the at<T>() method, always require the programmer to know exactly, or check manually, that the accessed matrix has the right type. I find this tedious, and a design flaw of both the C++ language and OpenCV's C++ API, which is why I stick to Python.

Ok, got it. Looks like the transform was calculated correctly all along, but I was printing it incorrectly.
After computing the transform, I now convert the result back to Point2f[] which are much easier to work with, then print them out.
using OpenCvSharp;
using System;

namespace AffineTransform
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Define the locations of the fiducials on the PCB in PCB coordinates
            Point2f[] pcbFiducials = new Point2f[]
            {
                new Point2f(0, 0),
                new Point2f(100, 0),
                new Point2f(100, -80)
            };

            // Define the same fiducial points as measured in machine coordinates, i.e. the position the PCB sits in the machine
            Point2f[] cameraFiducials = new Point2f[]
            {
                new Point2f(190.62f, -83.7f),
                new Point2f(290.24f, -74.99f),
                new Point2f(297.21f, -154.68f)
            };

            // Compute the affine transformation matrix
            Mat affineTransform = Cv2.GetAffineTransform(pcbFiducials, cameraFiducials);

            // Print the affine transformation matrix to check it's correctness
            Console.WriteLine("Affine Transformation Matrix:");
            for (int i = 0; i < affineTransform.Rows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < affineTransform.Cols; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write($"{affineTransform.At<double>(i, j)}\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            // Define the 3 'features' on the PCB we're interested in transforming to machine coordinates, in PCB coordinates
            Point2f[] pcbFeatures = new Point2f[]
            {
                new Point2f(24, -18),
                new Point2f(35, -62),
                new Point2f(74, -28)
            };

            // Convert feature points to a Mat object, as Mat is needed to pass to Transform() later
            Mat pcbFeaturesMat = new Mat(pcbFeatures.Length, 1, MatType.CV_32FC2, pcbFeatures);

            // Transform feature points to machine/camera coordinates, same reason as above
            Mat cameraFeaturesMat = new Mat();

            // Compute the actual transform
            Cv2.Transform(pcbFeaturesMat, cameraFeaturesMat, affineTransform);

            // Convert the result back to Point2f[], to make them much easier to actually use
            Point2f[] cameraFeatures = new Point2f[cameraFeaturesMat.Rows];
            for (int i = 0; i < cameraFeaturesMat.Rows; i++)
            {
                cameraFeatures[i] = new Point2f(cameraFeaturesMat.At<Point2f>(i).X, cameraFeaturesMat.At<Point2f>(i).Y);
            }

            // Print the transformed points
            Console.WriteLine("Transformed Points:");
            foreach (var point in cameraFeatures)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"X = {point.X}, Y = {point.Y}");
            }

            // Save the transformed points to a CSV file
            SavePointsToCsv(cameraFeatures, @"C:\users\user\desktop\cameraFeatures.csv");
        }

        static void SavePointsToCsv(Point2f[] points, string filename)
        {
            using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("X,Y");
                foreach (var point in points)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine($"{point.X},{point.Y}");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Saved transformed points to {filename}");
        }
    }
}

